# Codeigniter with MariaDB

Tags: database, mariadb, codeigniter-3

I recently upgraded the mysql database on a perfectly functioning web app to MariaDB. Now I am unable to get it working because it is not connecting to the database.

My dbdriver is set to 'mysqli'. 
I tried setting it to 'mysql' but I got different error.

Is is possible to have these both working together?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. 
It was a compatibility issue with EasyApache 4 on Cpanel/WHM. 
When I upgraded to MariaDB and activated EasyApache 4 the sites were no longer able to connect to the database. Once I reverted back to EasyApache 3. Everything started working again.